# Website redirects on old ip

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

A couple of weeks ago, we had a problem with our main server. After moving everything to a new server, we pointed our domain to the new IP. However, if the browser history is cleared, or if the website is opened from an incognito window, it still redirects to the old IP. The same happens if I browse website.domain.com instead of website.domain.com/Final. Since the person who was responsible for this got fired, and i am pretty new to Windows Server, i am stuck in this situation. Another thing to point,the old server is now used as a backup server, so it is active

Comment: Go to the DNS and check if there is any CNAME created with the old IP and make sure that the new server name has the new IP as Host . [Create a CNAME in Windows Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625726%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Disable WINS and test again. Seen that symptom on a bad WINS database. The WINS answer to IE, while nslookup do a DNS lookup only.

Comment: @Scorpion99 i cannot see any DNS Manager on my Windows server, even though i am logged in as an administrator.

Comment: @yagmoth555 done but however it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If the DNS is correctly configured to point the domain to the new IP maybe it's the Windows DNS caching. Try to run on a Windows machine *cmd* :

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

And test again.

Comment: i tried, and is not working. The DNS was set correctly, but maybe there is some kind of conflict, since the new server is the old backup server, so we have switched the domains in this order: the old backup.domain.com has now become site.domain.com, and the old site.domain.com is now backup2.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your forwarding is set correctly as it is just www forwarding to new IP.
if website.domain.com/Final is working, your IIS is not set correctly. When you reach the webserver with new IP, it would look for default site rather than a new site 'final' you have created.

Comment: ok, but as i said , i am a beginner in this issues, so can you give me a clue on how to check or resolve this issue?

Comment: What is your internal domain name? The issue could be with your internal DNS server as you will need to entry/edit the www DNS entry to point to new Web server IP. Also, please let me know where have you redirect the IPs, is it in your domain registrar?

Comment: Can you also let me know your real domain name?

Comment: As far as i know, yes, the domain is in the register..however, i cannot see a dns manager in my server even though i am logged in as an administrator.

Comment: DNS server can be part of same server or different Server. you will have a DNS server in your domain environment. It could be your main domain server also acting as DNS server